# Ubuntu 12.04 installation take too much time

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, wubi

I downloaded the ubuntu 12.04 source from official ubuntu site and after I try to install it by selecting the wubi.exe ,after the selecting the disk space and that ,it downloading  " amd64.tar.xz " file.It shows remaining time approximately 17h 30m ,and this process continues since last 2 hours...
**I downloaded and mounted the iso to install the 64 bit wubi, but every time I run it it gets stuck on "Downloading ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz .** And yeah,there is nothing wrong with internet connection

What should I do? Should I stop the installation process and leave it as it is..?

Comment: See what the installation is stuck on? Are you connected to (a slow) Internet? If yes it may be downloading the language packs; just disconnect from the Internet.

Comment: I downloaded and mounted the iso to install the 64 bit wubi, but every time I run it it gets stuck on "Downloading ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz . And yeah,there is nothing wrong with internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because its downloading some updates...try disconnecting you internet and continue your installation or why don't you try installing via USB making a boo-table Ubuntu USB drive...

Comment: I disconnected my internet but it still stuck on that process...
nothing happened..:(

Comment: maybe its downloading current version of Ubuntu 12.04..so if you have slow connection stop it and try booting with cd of usb...

Comment: Okay,thanks for help...
and finally I stop downloading and try to install something else than ubuntu